# Extract statusCode and message from exception message

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am calling a REST API and capturing response code and message in a table in case of any exception occurs.

```
catch (HttpClientErrorException ex) {
            logger.error("HttpClientErrorException occures in calling API");
            System.out.println(ex.getStatusCode());
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
```

**Output:**

```
HttpClientErrorException occures in calling API
400 BAD_REQUEST
400 : [{"errors":[{"status":"400","code":"1002","title":"Missing parameter","detail":"Id element is mandatory."}]}]
```

It seems I can get the required value *StatusCode and Message* from ex.getMessage() but how can I extract these values?

Comment: Deserialize the "errors" JSON array into POJOs with corresponding fields such as "status", "code", "title", "detail" etc. This assume that the server responds with the same fields on different errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see an answer from server being called in `message` property, so format depends on server/endpoint you are calling.
In this particular case you can parse JSON and work with it like an object and access all props. Simpler (but uglier) way is to extract all you need by regex.

But again, you will not have universal solution, since it depends on the servers answer.

Parsing as JSON with `Jackson` library example:

```java
public class ErrorMessage { // getter/setter are omitted
  String title;
  String detail;
  String code;
  String status;
}
```

```java
catch (HttpClientErrorException ex) {
  logger.error("HttpClientErrorException occures in calling API");
  ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
  ErrorMessage errorMessage = objectMapper.convertValue(ex.getMessage(), ErrorMessage.class);
  System.out.println(errorMessage.getTitle); // <- you have an object now, so you can do whatever you want
}
```

Comment: But the problem is, I am not able to parse it as JSON because the response is like 400 : [{....]} and even if I am using JSONArray..it's not reading it ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below:

```
((HttpServerErrorException.InternalServerError)e).getResponseBodyAsString()
```

This will give exception message without error code.